# How to log Serial data with time stamp?

Tags: timestamps, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino sending serial data to the computer. I'm able to view the data using a Serial console. But, I want to be able to log it with time stamp.

I want a ready made script or program that logs serial data with time-stamp automatically without me having to change much or mess with code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ts` program from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) to add a timestamp to each line.

```
{ echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar; } | ts
Dec 13 01:07:23 foo
Dec 13 01:07:24 bar
```

To read from the serial port and output to a file:

```
ts </dev/ttyS0 >arduino.log
```

(Replace `/dev/ttyS0` by the right path for the serial port device, .)

Comment: It caused cyclic resets of my Arduino which is probably caused by cyclic open / close port action and changing DTR line, connected to RESET.

Answer (score 5):

- I would recommend http://elinux.org/Grabserial.
- And formating **ts** output is a plus, it adds more time precission.

  `ts  [%H.%M.%.S]`

Comment: Thanks! Grabserial offers a lot more customization, including the ability to show offests and differences with different base times, restarting the logging based on patterns in the output, modifying serial line settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0  | ts >>arduino.log
```

or

```
sudo stdbuf -o0 cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | ts >>ttyS0.log
```

Comment: (1) Please don’t post code-only answers; rather, *explain* the essence of your answer.  (2) Why do you propose using `sudo`?  Don’t use `sudo` by default; use it only when you need to, and you *understand **why*** you need it.  (3) Why use `cat`, especially in your first answer?  Your `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | ts >>arduino.log` command is equivalent (except for the tty name and the `>>`) to the `ts </dev/ttyS0 >arduino.log` command which was given almost nine years ago.  (4) What’s the benefit of using `stdbuf` here, and what does `-o0` do?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://tio.github.io - it supports logging with various timestamp formats. For example:

`tio /dev/ttyUSB0 --log --timestamp --timestamp-format=24-hour`